Can a constructor of an instance of a template access the template of its private members?
Let's suppose we want to make a custom Array template that can hold an Array of any type (I know there's the standard library, but I am just learning how templates work.) We created a simple Animal class and whenever we want to create our customed array of that animal class, then we call a special constructor that would not normally be called if we created an array of any other type.
Take a look at the following code:

// 1
// Array Template
template <class T>
class Array {
    Array(int size);
    Array(const Array &rhs);
    ~Array() { delete[] pType; }

    Array& operator=(const Array&);
    T& operator[](int offset) const { return pType[offset]; }

    int GetSize() { return itsSize; }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Array<T>&);
private:
    T* pType;
    int itsSize;
};

// 2
// Animal class
class Animal {
public:
    Animal(int size);
    Animal();
    ~Animal();

    int GetWeight() { return itsWeight; }
    void SetWeight(int weight) { itsWeight = weight; }

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Animal&);
private:
    int itsWeight;
};

// 3
// default array constructor
template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(int size):itsSize(size)
{
    pType = new T[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        pType[i] = T(0);
    }
}

// 4
// constructor to be called ONLY when we create an Animal Array
Array<Animal>::Array(int AnimalArraySize)
{
    itsSize = AnimalArraySize;
    pType = new Animal[AnimalArraySize];
}


Now let's take a look at the main() function.
int main() {
    Array<Animal> animalArray(4);
    return 0;
}

It states the following error!

Array::Array(int size) [with T = Animal] is inaccessible

What going on here? I would assume part 4 of my code is the one that's running and since it's an Array constructor, it should have access to both pType and size. If any explanation can be provided, then that would be great.

The error is because you forgot public: before your public members in Array.

The next error you will see, you cannot specialise just the constructor. You specialise whole template (here whole class) or nothing.

You went through your big discussion of how Animal is special, but did you test the common case? Are you able to define an Array<int>? Eliminating Animal from your question would greatly simplify it and make it applicable to more people in the future. Removing the template would be a good next simplification step.

Here is an example that demonstrates how to specialize your Array class for type Animal. Comments provide many other tips, as well.
